# How do you use StackPanel.FindName in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a stack panel with a set of four image buttons inside of it. When I try to search by the name of the image button it comes back null. What is wrong with my code?

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="swatchClearStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
     <imgbutton:ImageButton x:Name="ClearSwatchColor1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonClearSwatchColor}" Margin="5,8,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Visibility="Hidden" Click="ClearSwatchColor_Click"  />
     <imgbutton:ImageButton x:Name="ClearSwatchColor2"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonClearSwatchColor}"  Margin="5,18,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Visibility="Hidden" Click="ClearSwatchColor_Click"/>
     <imgbutton:ImageButton x:Name="ClearSwatchColor3"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonClearSwatchColor}"  Margin="5,18,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Visibility="Hidden" Click="ClearSwatchColor_Click"/>
     <imgbutton:ImageButton x:Name="ClearSwatchColor4"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonClearSwatchColor}" Margin="5,20,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Visibility="Hidden" Click="ClearSwatchColor_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**And the C#:**
**EDIT:** Note: The button name is hard coded to show that it cannot find it, the end result will be a variable as its one method that several buttons will reference. This code triggers after the UI has loaded. (The user clicks a button and this code runs. Same window, same everything.)

```
var swatchClearButton = swatchClearStackPanel.FindName("ClearSwatchColor1");
```

Comment: Why do you want to do a FindName, when you already have a name for the ImageButton you need?

Comment: Why you cannot access it directly by name `ClearSwatchColor1.xxx`

Comment: Your code seems fine, it should work. are you calling it before the UI is rendered maybe?

Comment: Maybe you do not have worded the question well. Attach the component definition imgbutton

Comment: Please try to access after initializecomponent if in case you are using in your constructor.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal - I cannot call the button directly because the name will change, sorry I had hard coded the name in to prove that with it in it still doesn't work. It will be a variable.

Comment: This is not before the UI is rendered, the user has to take action (i.e. click a button) in order for the code to trigger